# versioning & store vm image

Tags: svn, virtual-machines

How would you store many vm images and versioning it?

SVN bindiff is slow i think....

Answer (score 0):

SVN would not be very useful for storing VM because you do not need all SCM features (like branching or merging) for this kind of data.

Use another repository with the possibility of labeling or referencing a specific set of data.
This [SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/95397/are-whole-vm-images-backed-up-on-amazon-ec2-s3) offers a good alternative through [Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [rdiff-backups](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) - i use it to keep last few backups of vms. you can use snapshots on your SAN too... if you store vms on it. but both methods are quite costly - it's better to do backups on the higher level than sector-by-sector vm image.